# Image share on LinkedIn via API gives CLIENT_ERROR

Tags: javascript, node.js, linkedin-api

I am trying to create image share on linkedIn via API.
I have followed all the steps mentioned in documentation which are

- Register upload
- Upload image to given URL
- Verify uploaded image

I am uploading image using CURL in nodejs as follows

```
const util = require('util');
const exec = util.promisify(require('child_process').exec);
const {
    stdout,
    stderr,
} = await exec(`curl -v -H "Authorization: Bearer ${accessToken}" --upload-file ${path} -k '${url}'`);
console.log('stdout:', stdout);
console.log('stderr:', stderr);
if (stderr.length > 0) {
    console.log('std err');
    const e = new Error();
    e.message = 'There was an error with CURL request';
    e.statusCode = 500;
    throw e;
}

if (stdout == '201' || stdout == ' 201' || parseInt(stdout) == 201 || stdout.indexOf('000') !== -1) {
    console.log('upload success to linked');
    return true;
}
```

File uploads successfully. But whenever I check the uploaded asset via

https://api.linkedin.com/v2/assets/{asserURN} endpoint. I get following error

```
    {
    "serviceRelationships": [
        {
            "identifier": "urn:li:userGeneratedContent",
            "relationshipType": "OWNER"
        }
    ],
    "recipes": [
        {
            "recipe": "urn:li:digitalmediaRecipe:feedshare-image",
            "status": "CLIENT_ERROR"
        }
    ],
    "mediaTypeFamily": "STILLIMAGE",
    "created": 1562182923304,
    "lastModified": 1562182928516,
    "id": "C5122AQEktBmXOb4QUg",
    "status": "ALLOWED"
}
```

IDK why I am getting **CLIENT_ERROR**. It has been 5 days since i'm banging my head with this code but no clue. Neither LinkedIn API docs says anything about this.

I have tried following things

- Specifying Content-Type header as application/octet
- Specifying Content-Type header as image/png or mimeType of the image

NOTHING WORKS...I am really fed up with this. Kindly point me to right direction.

Comment: I am hitting a similar issue with a multipart video upload.  For what it's worth, small videos (< 200MB) and images are working just fine for me.

Comment: I have faced the same issue for the last 1 week. Did you get any solution to this?

Comment: Its been long since i worked on this. I dont remember now :D
Anyway i THINK i used binary file upload. Then it worked

Comment: What do you mean binary file upload?